# Как в Yii2 сделать запрос к двум таблицам, связанным через вспомогательную таблицу?

Tags: active-record, yii2, yii, sql

У меня в проекте есть три сущности:

- Заказ (order)
- Позиция заказа (position)
- Товарная позиция (good)

В одном заказе может быть несколько позиций, каждая позиция - это запись с внешними ключами (заказ, товар). Чтобы выбрать все товары, входящие в заказ, я могу сделать на чистом SQL такой запрос:

```
   SELECT g.*
     FROM ord o
 LEFT JOIN position p ON o.id = p.id_order
LEFT JOIN good g ON p.id_good = g.id
    WHERE o.id = $id
```

Соответственно, в Yii2, работающем с MySQL, вполне сработает такой вариант:

```
$query = 'SELECT g.*
            FROM ord o
       LEFT JOIN position p ON o.id = p.id_order
       LEFT JOIN good g ON p.id_good = g.id
           WHERE o.id = :id';

return Yii::$app->db
      ->createCommand($query, [':session' => $session])
      ->queryAll();
```

Вариант рабочий, но не в духе [генеральной линии партии](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#relations-with-junction-table), которая рекомендует писать код так, чтобы свободно плавать между различными СУБД без переписывания запросов.

Я несколько раз читал блок про [Relations with Junction Table](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#relations-with-junction-table), однако как перейти от SQL к Active Record в данном случае пока не понял. По сути, в модели заказов должен появиться новый метод, который будет возвращать экземпляры товарных позиций:

```
public function getReservedGoods() {
        return $this->hasMany(Good::className(), ['id' => 'id_good'])
            ->viaTable(Position::tableName(), ['id_order' => 'id'])
}
```

Здесь я радостно утыкаюсь в эксепшн:

```
Unknown Method – yii\base\UnknownMethodException
Calling unknown method: app\controllers\GoodController::hasMany()
```

Очень хотелось бы пинка в нужном направлении от знатоков Yii2 - что делать-то? Добавлять аналогичный метод в таблицу товаров? Уверен, ответ на поверхности, но я пока его не вижу.

Comment: зачем вы связи в контроллер пихаете?

Answer (score 2):

Ниже приведён рабочий пример связи M:M для тегов к статьям.

**Модель "Articles"**

```
class Articles extends ActiveRecord
{
    public static function tableName()
    {
       return 'articles';
    }

    public function getTags()
    {
        return $this
            ->hasMany(Tags::className(), ['id' => 'tag_id'])       
            ->viaTable(TagsArticles::tableName(), ['resource_id' => 'id']);            
    }
}
```

**Модель сводной "pivot" таблицы "TagsArticles"**

```
class TagsArticles extends ActiveRecord
{
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'tags_articles';
    }
}
```

**Модель "Tags"**

```
class Tags extends ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'tags';
    }
}
```

Все модели должны наследоваться от `yii\db\ActiveRecord`.

P.S. Есть стойкое ощущение, что Вы метод `getReservedGoods()` вызываете из контроллера `app\controllers\GoodController`, кода как он должен быть расположен в модели `Orders`. [@Etki](/users/16095/etki) был прав говоря об этом в комментариях под Вашим вопросом.

Answer (score 1):

Добиться некоторого уровня абстракции можно, не используя ActiveRecord, например, так:

```
 $query=new Query();
 $query->addSelect(['g.*'])
         ->from ([Order::tableName().' o'])
         ->leftJoin(Position::tableName().' p','o.id = p.id_order')
         ->leftJoin(Good::tableName(). ' g','p.id_good = g.id')
         ->where(['o.id'=>':id'],[':id'=>$id]);

 return $query->all();
```

Если нужен именно ActiveRecord, то ваша модель должна быть унаследована от ActiveRecord, и функция getReservedGoods() должна быть методом этой модели, не контроллера.

Answer (score -1):

Вам всего лишь нужно познать [релейшены](http://yiiframework.ru/doc/guide/ru/database.arr).